Solution to $\cos x+\tan x=1$
On a recent test, we were given this problem to solve:
$$\tan(x)+\cos(x)=1$$
However, no one was able to determine a solution with the proper formatting required for the test. By "proper formatting", you should have been able to break the problem down into simple $\sin$ and $\cos$ equations to solve, such as $\sin(x)=1$. (Excuse my improper vocabulary)
If this problem cannot be broken down into such parts, please explain why it cannot.

Is this from a freshman Calc course?

We can write $\tan(x) = \sin(x)/\cos(x)$ so the equation becomes
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} + \cos(x) = 1$$
Multiplying on both sides by $\cos(x)$,
$$\sin(x)+\cos^2(x) = \cos(x)$$
Here's where things get trickier.
Subtracting $\cos^2(x)$,
$$\sin(x) = \cos(x)-\cos^2(x)$$
Now squaring both sides and using the Pythagorean Identity,
$$1 - \cos^2(x) = \sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x)-2\cos^3(x) +\cos^4(x)$$
So we have a polynomial equation for $\cos(x)$ as follows:
$$(\cos(x))^4 - 2 (\cos(x))^3 + 2(\cos(x))^2 - 1 = 0$$
Now this has one obvious root $\cos x = 1$ giving $x = 2\pi n$ and a root $\cos x \approx -0.544$ which is an annoying irrational which you cannot solve during a test. This, of course, gives more solutions, some of which are extraneous.

In Conclusion, you could not be expected to find any solution other than the obvious $x = 2\pi n$ in a test, and probably not by anything other than inspection.

There is in fact a somewhat explicit form one can give to the value $-0.544$, using the formula given here. That yields $\displaystyle \cos x=\frac13-\frac23 \sqrt{2}\sinh\left(\sinh^{-1}\frac{17}{2\sqrt{2}}\right).$ But this only drives home your conclusion that it's not plausible it is to find a nontrivial solution by analytical means.

@Semiclassical I was proceeding by the route of the generic formula for the cubic, but that's an interesting result!

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0nryox02wu

If you use the tangent half angle substitution, you need to solve $t^3+t^2-t+1=0$ which gives $$t=-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{4}{3} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3}
\cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{19}{8}\right)\right)$$ and then $x=2\tan^{-1}(t)$

Interesting approach, although we never learned this method of solving, it is a very curious solution. Thanks for the alternative answers as well. I wonder why this was on our test.

Brute force gives cos $x=\frac13\left(1+(-17+\sqrt{297})^{\frac13}+(-17-\sqrt{297})^{\frac13}\right)$.  Reasonable for a test on cubic equations.  Bit of a nightmare to mark though, given the range of correct expressions for the answer.

Let $\cos x =u$. Using trig to put all into $\cos (x)$,
$$ u^4-2u^3+2 u^2 + 0 u -1= (u-1)(u^3-u^2+u+1)=0$$
whose real solutions are
$$u=1, u\approx -0.543689 = -k $$
solution of $u=1$ is $x_1= 2 m \pi$
The cubic has two complex and only one real root.
If $ \cos \alpha = k $ then the roots are  $$ x_{2,3}=  \alpha+(2n+1) \pi.$$

Just for your curiosity
If we look for the first negative zero of function
$$f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos^2(x)- \cos(x)$$ by inspection, the solution is close to $-\frac {2\pi}3$.
Let $x=t-\frac {2\pi}3$ and consider the function
$$g(t)=\sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi
   }{6}-t\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{6}-t\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{6}-t\right)$$
$$g'(t)=-\sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{6}-t\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{6}-t\right)-2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{6}-t\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{6}-t\right)$$
Using the first iteration of Newton method with $t_0=0$ is
$$t_1=-\frac{15-8 \sqrt{3}}{22} \quad \implies \quad x_1=-2.14638$$ which is not too bad since the "exact" solution is $-2.14562$.
Doing the same with Halley method
$$t_1=-\frac{2 \left(9-4 \sqrt{3}\right)}{5
   \left(11+3 \sqrt{3}\right)} \quad \implies \quad x_1=-2.14556$$
Doing the same with Householder method
$$t_1=-\frac{5 \left(13
   \sqrt{3}-15\right)}{337+229\sqrt{3}}\quad \implies \quad x_1=-2.14562$$

The given equation can be rearranged as follows:
$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=1-\cos x$$
$$\implies\frac{2\sin\frac{x}2\cos\frac{x}2}{\cos^2\frac{x}2-\sin^2\frac{x}2}=2\sin^2\frac{x}2\tag{1}$$
Here, we get a solution, $\sin\frac{x}2=0\implies\frac{x}2=n\pi,n\in\mathbb Z\implies x=2n\pi, n\in\mathbb Z$. Now, we can cancel the factor of $2\sin\frac{x}2$ from both sides of $(1)$ to get the remaining solutions:
$$\tan\frac{x}2\left(\cos^2\frac{x}2-\sin^2\frac{x}2\right)=1$$
This can be solved by rewriting everything in terms of $\tan\frac{x}2$ as suggested by Claude Leibovici:
$$\tan\frac{x}2\left(1-\tan^2\frac{x}2\right)=1+\tan^2\frac{x}2$$
$$\implies \tan^3\frac{x}2+\tan^2\frac{x}2-\tan\frac{x}2+1=0$$
This cubic equation doesn’t have “nice” roots like $x=2n\pi$.
